# onclick button get the value of selected (checkbox) value

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="chks" ng-repeat="request in pendingRequest">                                    
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk" ng-model="pendingRequest" id="chk1" ng-click="pendingUser(request.user_id)">
 <label for="chk1">{{request.first_name}} {{request.last_name}}</label>
</div>

<button type="button" ng-click="checkVal()" class="btn btn-default next-step"><span class="next-step">Resend Linking Request</span></button>

var selectUser = '';
$scope.pendingUser = function(user) {
    selectUser = user;
} 

$scope.checkVal = function() {
    if (selectUser) {
       alert(selectUser);
    } else {
       alert("CheckBox is not checked.");
    }
}
```

How can I check on click checkVal button function has user_id.

on bases checkbox click get the user_id in Angularjs.

Comment: You have `ng-repeat` there. What happens when there are multiple items? Returning an array?

Comment: Yes pendingRequest has an array

Comment: No I mean the result of the check. Should it return checked when some are checked and some are not?

Comment: It should return the check value

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to push the value entries from the checkbox.

```
$scope.nameSelected= [];
```

Give a single value for the checkbox. I'm assuming that to be the first name.

```
 $scope.getAllSelected = function(){          
            angular.forEach($scope.first_name,function(key,value){
                if(key)
                    $scope.nameSelected.push(value)
            });
    console.log($scope.nameSelected)
        }
```

Remove the unwanted ng-click from the checkbox input entry. getAllSelected can be done in the ng-click on the submit button you've there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="chks" ng-repeat="request in pendingRequest">                                    
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" ng-model="pendingRequest" id="chk1" ng-click="pendingUser(request.user_id)">
    <label for="chk1">{{request.first_name}} {{request.last_name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Why would you ng-repeat over the same model than your checkbox is ? Can you provide a plunker or something.

```
$scope.checkVal = function(){

    if (selectUser) {
        alert(selectUser);
    } else {
       alert("CheckBox is not checked.");
    }
}
```

The selectUser is undefined there, is it supposed to be a single user (and you should pass it in params then), or the whole array pendingRequest ?

If you want to check if each request is selected then you could just bind your checkbox to request.selected and return in the check request.selected
Which would be something like that :

```
$scope.checkVal = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.pendingRequest, function(request) {
        if (request.selected)
            alert(request)
        else
            alert("Not selected")
    })
}
```

Comment: pendingRequest consists of array values where in user_id exist I want that user_id on each checkbox when i invovked button each selected user_id get notify

Comment: Check the edit i just made then, and don't forget to change the ng-model of your input to request.selected